# How to Get a Color Value or Brush of a Button?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have created a control template for button to change the colors during the **press event**.

I have created a button with the template as

```
            <Button Content="Sample" Height="100" Background="Blue" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="Orange" Template="{StaticResource NewButtonStyle}"/>
```

and the template is

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="NewButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Grid Background="Transparent">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedHighlightBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Green"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" >
                <Border x:Name="PressedHighlightBackground" Background="Transparent">
                    <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                </Border>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Here what I have done is during the press event, I have changed the border color and background color to some other colors by setting the values to some colors.

But what I need is, instead of setting the values to some other colors I need to exchange the colors of background and border during the press event. i.e. Background color should be assigned to border and similarly border color should be assigned to background.

Please somebody help me to achieve this.

Comment: what are the values for the background and borderbrush?

Comment: Have you looked at TemplateBinding? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758288.aspx you'd need to use it with a VisualState.

Comment: I tried using TemplateBinding. It worked only for assigning border color background but the background color to border have made the border just transparent.